# umount dev/sda1 to mount dev/sda1 or change partition to ntfs

Tags: mount, umount

well I installed Ubuntu but I can't play many games I would like too and I can't change to NTFS with Gparted because i'm using /dev/sda1 and I would like to know if its possible to change with commands at cmds but only using one pen drive thanks :)

Comment: why do you need NTFS and which games are you unable to play?

Comment: because i want get windows 7... i cant play with my 100 fps in CS and i cant play World of Warcraft!

Comment: Have you tried `Wine`?

Comment: if i didn't try i wouldnt be enable to play

Comment: You can play windows games on Ubuntu using `wine`.

Comment: man are u thinking about what u saying? if i didnt know that i wouldnt play CS 1.6

Comment: all you need to do is create 3 partitions,one for windows one for Ubuntu and one NTFS for data.reinstall everything

Comment: how i would do that? any tutorial?

Comment: @adityapatil wrong.You dont need separate partition for data.There are programs for windows for EXT4 filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

You cant resize an parttition you are using.You have to unmount it first so if you booted from the same partition then you cant resize it.

You have to resize the partition in a computer which didnt boot from the partition you are trying to resize.

You dont have to use commands. Utilities like GParted are much more user friendly.

Comment: teach me how please... i tried gparted but they say i cant umout and i cant resize :\ but i still have dev/sda2 but its only 3gb

Comment: @user250453 How did you "try GParted"? You wont be able to unmount it or resize or whatever if you are using it. Try from a different Operating System/pendrive/PC

Comment: which operating system? ye i tried but i couldnt change... i just have pendrive its possible to change with it to windows 7?

Comment: @user250453 it is hard to understand what you are writing.If you have another OS on the same pendrive then boot from it and resize partition in it.Im repaeting myself again: You cant resize Ubuntu while you are using the same Ubuntu!

Comment: @user250453 you can do the above or use another storage device with OS and use that OS to resize Ubuntu

Comment: I can use my bootable USB with same Ubuntu to do that bro??

Comment: @user250453 you dont understand anything I wrote.. so lets solve it this way. Answer my questions and you will know what to do.Questions:Is your whole pendrive one partition? Do you have another pendrive or other storage device?

Comment: yes i have two pendrives one with 8gb and other with 2gb... with 8gb has windows 7 ultimate wich one i want it to install in this PC and other with ubuntu 12.04

Comment: 8gb has windows installeD or installeR? where you gonna install Windows?

Comment: i want to install in this PC .

Comment: @user250453 where in this PC?Maybe into a cpu? Seriously on what storage device and partition you will install?

Comment: man im using /Dev/sda1 with ubuntu and i want to install windows 7 in that! but i cant unmount, change partition and im asking if its possible to change it

Comment: so if you wan to replace install Windows where Ubuntu is you have to format ubuntu first.

Comment: how i format ubuntu?

Comment: maybe u dont understand my problem thanks anyway!

Comment: @user250453 you format it in another OS like Windows or Mac OS

Comment: I can't man you don't understand that I have no CD and I haven't NTFS partition?

Comment: @user250453 you are very hard to understand.. if you also dont have usb then go to your neighbor or friend to format it

Comment: @user250453 please upvote me for all my effort for you and select best answer so you free me from question ban!

Comment: i can't upvote u because u didnt help lol and u cant read what i said to i said i have 2 pendrives -.-' bye man u dont understand